# Why is my Rails callback being called twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have an after_commit on: :create callback in my model, and it is being called twice. There are six methods in this callback, some of which are inserting into my database. I am afraid things are going to slow down AND my database is going to grow too quickly.

What's odd is that my before_create after_create callbacks are only executing once. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: use after_save instead of after_commit

Long answer: [How to organize complex callbacks in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532911/how-to-organize-complex-callbacks-in-rails/11544635#11544635)

Comment: Show us some code, are you calling save inside your callback?

Comment: No, I am not, should I be?

`after_commit :func1, :func2, :func3, :func4, func5, :func6, on: :create`

Despite it being on create, `model.save` seems to be triggering the callback. Is that normal?

Comment: @Bholzer are you sure the `on: :create` option is supported? I couldn't find the documentation for it (however the documentation is pretty bad, so I might be missing something). Instead I found `after_commit_on_create`, which might be what you should be using?

Comment: Yeah, it is supported. Extremely hard to find though, since like you said, the documentation is awful. Found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10356903/1566664) that shows its usage. 
The one you posted I believe requires a plugin.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating why `after_commit on: :create` would be called multiple times in this case? I couldn't find a clear answer in the linked discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I found using before_create solved the issue.

When you use the:

```
user = User.new
user.save
```

You are firing the before_save hook each time.

```
before_create
```

should work