# Multiple after_commit for the same method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback

How can I specify multiple callbacks to the method?

```
after_commit :assign_awards, on: [:create, :destroy]

private

def assign_awards
  AwardsWorker.perform_async(self.id, self.class.name, self.user_id)
end
```

Error:

```
/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:404: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
...(transaction_include_action?(:[:create, :destroy]))
```

For some reason, the callback isn't executed with this either:

```
after_commit :assign_awards, on: :create
after_commit :assign_awards, on: :destroy
```

It only works if I two different methods like:

```
after_commit :assign_awards_create, on: :create
after_commit :assign_awards_destroy, on: :destroy

private

def assign_awards_create
  AwardsWorker.perform_async(self.id, self.class.name, self.user_id)
end

def assign_awards_destroy
  AwardsWorker.perform_async(self.id, self.class.name, self.user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this answer shows the opposite:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356903/1023609.

Maybe it is a problem with the Rails version you are using.